# Google Visualization API .net?

Tags: serialization, json.net

How can i use data in my .NET app that is coming in google's visualisation api json format? Can't imagine at the moment how to use this data.

Do i have to parse the json to an object by myself? Can i use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize it? For now i have no idea how start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Data looks like this:

```
{
  cols: [
    {id: '1', label: 'Name', type: 'string'},
    {id: '2', label: 'Age', type: 'number'},
    {id: '3', label: 'Birthdate', type: 'date'}
  ],
  rows: [
    {c:[{v: 'Dan'}, {v: 18.0, f: 'eighteen'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Frank'}, {v: 19.0, f: 'nineteen'}, {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}]},
    {c:[{v: 'Esther'}, {v: 20.0, f: 'twenty'}, {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}]}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can i use Json.NET to deserialize it?

Yes. That's what it's for.

> For now i have no idea how start with this. Any help is appreciated.

[The manual](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

Comment: thank you for the answer. i forgot to mention that i'm pretty new to .NET. I read the manual and tried to figure out how to deserialize my data structure. But for now i'm more confused than before reading the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json deserialisation via the DataContractJsonSerializer class in the  System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace. It's pretty similar to XML Serialisation in that you create a bunch of data classes, dress them with attributes and chuck the Json into a deserializer.

The article below explains how work with Json with a Google web search example:

http://www.ben-morris.com/google-search-api-deserialize-json-output-net

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but for future seekers take a look here:

https://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/

I'm using it without any problem.

Sample code:

```
 DataTable tbl = DatabaseEnquiry(sqlcommand, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", true);
 return new Bortosky.Google.Visualization.GoogleDataTable(tbl).GetJson().ToString();
```

Alternatively you can use JavaScriptSerializer:

```
DataTable tbl = DatabaseEnquiry(sqlcommand, DATE_IN, DATE_OUT, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", true);
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try
{
    var linqResults = from DataRow row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
                      select new
                      {
                          avgft = row.Field<object>("AVG FT"),
                          minft = row.Field<object>("MIN FT"),
                          maxft = row.Field<object>("MAX FT"),
                          avgffc = row.Field<object>("AVG FFC"),
                          minffc = row.Field<object>("MIN FFC"),
                          maxffc = row.Field<object>("MAX FFC"),
                          avgtt = row.Field<object>("AVG TT"),
                          mintt = row.Field<object>("MIN TT"),
                          maxtt = row.Field<object>("MAX TT"),
                          avgtfc = row.Field<object>("AVG TFC"),
                          mintfc = row.Field<object>("MIN TFC"),
                          maxtfc = row.Field<object>("MAX TFC")
                      };
    js.Serialize(linqResults, sb);
}
catch (InvalidCastException e)
{
    logger.Debug(e.StackTrace);
    return null;
}
return sb.ToString();
```

}